# C# find a matching phrase in string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, contains

I have a concurrent bag filled with strings like this:

```
var bag = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
```

The collection contains 100 strings from which I need to find a phrase like in following example:

```
"Galaxy S7" - search phrase
```

And lets say the titles are:

```
Samsung galaxy S4
Samsung galaxy S5
Samsung galaxy S6
Samsung galaxy S7
```

The output that I would get is:

```
Samsung galaxy S4
Samsung galaxy S5
Samsung galaxy S6
```

I've tried it with the method "Contains" that string has like following:

```
var _items = new ConcurrentBag<SearchItems>();
Parallel.For(0, xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("item").Count, index =>
{
    if (negative != null && negative != "")
    {
        if (!xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("title").Item(index).InnerText.Contains(negative))
        {
            _items.Add(new SearchItems() { 
                    CurrentPrice = Convert.ToDouble(xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("convertedCurrentPrice").Item(index).InnerText), 
                    ItemID = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("itemId").Item(index).InnerText, 
                    Title = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("title").Item(index).InnerText });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _items.Add(new SearchItems() { 
                CurrentPrice = Convert.ToDouble(xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("convertedCurrentPrice").Item(index).InnerText), 
                ItemID = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("itemId").Item(index).InnerText, 
                Title = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("title").Item(index).InnerText });
    }
});
```

The problem is, contains is not case sensitive and if I try to exclude

s7

and

S7

I don't get same results... I need some solution that is not case sensitive :/

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried 'String.ToLower()'? Do this before doing anything with the string so it converts the string to lowercase, therefore when matching, the case will not matter.

Comment: convert you string into lower case before running it into contains.
String.ToLower()

Comment: @KyleStankovich you mean like this: negative.ToLower() ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx  is all about string comparison.

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain it still doens't works for some reason... maybe it works only for upper case letters?

Comment: @User987 Yeah. Here is a straight up example.

`string str = "Hello World";
Console.WriteLine(str.ToLower());`

The output world be **hello world**

Comment: xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("title").Item(index).InnerText.ToLower().Contains(negative.ToLower())

Comment: @MuhammadSaqlain, Kyle, it still doesn't works, it adds the items to list which have S7 included in them.. Maybe this is due to the fact that it's running thrught a parallel loop instead of a regular one ?

Comment: If you need full text search, perhaps something like [Lucene.Net](https://lucenenet.apache.org/) would be a better choice. It is more involved, but will do what you want.